# Automatic replacement of indirect imports

Tags: python, refactoring, python-import, automated-refactoring

I have a small module that defines a function:

```
# small_file.py
def func():
...
```

I have a larger module that does a wildcard import of that one:

```
# giant_file.py
from small_file import *
...
```

I have hundreds of other files that indirectly import the function via `giant_file`:

```
# file1.py
from giant_file import func
...

# file2.py
import giant_file.func
...

# file3.py
from giant_file import func, something_not_in_small_file
...
```

I would like to automatically change all these other files to import directly from `small_file.py`. This is to avoid the overhead of loading all of `giant_file.py`.

My question is this: **is there a good way to automatically change all these files to import directly?**

My default plan is to write a [redbaron](https://redbaron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)-based tool, but I'm hoping there might be a more lightweight approach utilizing an IDE's refactoring capabilities.

Comment: Just use your favorite text search and replace tool?

Comment: @JanWilamowski Done naively, that will break on `from giant_file import func, something_else`.

Comment: Then don't do it naively. `grep` out the imports and inspect them. You can probably clear out most of them easily.

Comment: What if I want to do the same for thousands of other functions, defined in hundreds of other sister files to `small_file.py`? I'm looking for an automated solution.

Comment: Since IDEs usually have regex based find-and-replace options, a really basic way of automating it could be [something like this](https://regexr.com/6eh90). It's not really analyzing the import statements, but you can avoid replacement in situations like file3.py where it shouldn't be done (by not matching commas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by writing a static analysis tool that analyzes my entire codebase and constructs an AST for each file. Using the AST's, the tool traverses imports and attributes each symbol read to an original assignment. It then rewrites all the imports in each file with direct-imports (eliminating unused imports along the way).

There are some potential pathological cases that the tool misses, such as dynamically constructing strings and then assigning to them via `globals()`. But it works for most "normal" code.

I used [redbaron](https://pypi.org/project/redbaron/) for this. If I could do it again, I would use [LibCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead, as redbaron has various bugs and unsupported python language elements, while LibCST appears to be more mature and actively maintained.